# Meteor: Can I use reactive vars outside of template helpers?

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

I thought that every function containing a reactive Variable (e.g. session variable) is alway rerun whenever the variable changes. This happens when I use them within a template helper:

```
<template name="temp">
   {{reactiveHelper}}
</template>

Template.temp.helpers({
    reactiveHelper: function(){
        return Session.get('reactVar');
    }
});
```

However I would like to have the same behavier for functions that are not included in a template. e.g.:

```
reactiveFunction = function(){
    console.log(Session.get('reactVar'));
};
```

Is this something that reactivity is not designed for or am I getting something wrong?

Comment: See the [reactivity](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/reactivity) section of the docs to gain a better understanding of reactive contexts and data sources. To create an arbitrary reactive context, you'll need to use an [autorun](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/tracker_autorun).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap your function in an `Tracker.autorun`

http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/tracker_autorun

```
  Tracker.autorun(function(){
    console.log(Session.get('reactVar'));
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Totally forgot about it, even though I have used it before :)